# Edited vs. saved answer differs

Tags: bug

What's wrong with the database/website engine?

The edit window differs from the saved [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285890/93229):

**Edit window with preview:**

[image]

**After saving any modification the 120g is automagically replaced with 100%:**

[image]

In the **edit history** everything is [fine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/285890/revisions). Emptying browser caches doesn't help.

Comment: Yup, [source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/b1ab0079-eaf5-46de-a411-dd01c0e6cf4c/view-source) shows ‘120g’, how peculiar.